# The following JavaScript with google maps error appeared: NotLoadingAPIFromGoogleMapsError

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

> Google Maps JavaScript API error: NotLoadingAPIFromGoogleMapsError

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This error message:

> Google Maps JavaScript API error: NotLoadingAPIFromGoogleMapsError

is a little misleading.

The description from the documentation:

> **NotLoadingAPIFromGoogleMapError**
>     The Maps JavaScript API must be downloaded directly from Google's servers.
>   The script element that loads the Maps JavaScript API is not being included correctly on your page. In order for the API to work correctly, it must be loaded directly from https://maps.googleapis.com.
>
> See [Loading the Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API).

It also occurs when using the original location for the google maps API (which worked for years):

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js
```

Changing that to (per the documentation link above):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js
```

fixes the error.